# Typescript typings for momentjs and moment-range not working together

Tags: momentjs, typescript-typings

I am using `momentjs` and `moment-range` with a Typescript, so I have install typings for `moment-range` from `npm @types`, and the typing for `momentjs` comes with it.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-range';
...
private tableDatePeriod: moment.Range;
```

but on compile I am getting this error - `[ts] Module 'moment' has no exported member 'Range'.`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { default as DateRange } from 'moment-range';

let Range=new DateRange(dayFrom, dayTo);
Range.toArray('days');

let DatesArray=[];
diffDatesArray.push(moment(some_prop_from_array._d).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

Comment: this is useful but with a previous version of moment and moment-range

Comment: for me it works for versions `"moment": "^2.16.0",
    "moment-range": "^2.2.0"`

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me for versions:

- moment: 2.17.1
- moment-range: 2.2.0
- @types/moment-range: 2.0.33

The problem is that `moment-range.js` does not export any new entity for the range functionality, it extends `moment` type with range functionalities. Therefore these functionalities should be imported from `moment`.

```
import {Moment, Range, range as RangeConstructor} from "moment";
```

This import *loads* the `moment-range` functionalities from `moment`. In this example I import `Range` interface and `range` factory method (to create/construct ranges).
That should be enough, but in case you are using some type of AMD or similar dependency, the `moment-range` module should be loaded (required using AMD terms).
The following is the hack that *works* for me:

```
import DateRange = require("moment-range");
DateRange;
```

The first import includes `moment-range`module as a dependency of the current module, therefore it is loaded as required first.
The second line does nothing, but the TypeScript compiler removes unused dependencies, so the former imported dependency must be invoked in some way in order to avoid such compiler optimization.

In reference to your question, you can now instantiate the variable:

```
private tableDatePeriod: Range;
```

And initialize:

```
tableDatePeriod = RangeConstructor('2016-01-09', '2016-01-10');
```